# Unable to construct DataTable using data retrieved from Parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, datatables

In my project I'm using `Parse.com` as server and database, and `DataTable` plugin to create a table showing the data returned. There's no problem when I use a predefined `json` file, but when I try to construct a local `json` file using the data returned from `Parse.com` I get an error. It seems no matter what I do, the table creation process is run first and only afterwards the `json object` is created.

JSfiddle with the relevant code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t6xj4wks/5/). Please note that due to the large amount of code I did not provide a working sample, but only the relevant part.

```
function getDataFromParse(){
    console.log("test function run");

       var loc_json={
          "data":[]
      };
                        //get data from parse
              var parseTable = Parse.Object.extend("parseTable");
                var tableObj = new parseTable();
              var query = new Parse.Query(parseTable);
              var count=0;

              query.descending("createdAt");
              query.find({
                  success: function(resultArr){
                                console.log("retreiving data from parse");
                        for(var i=0;i<resultArr.length;i++){
                                query.get(resultArr[i].id,{
                                  success: function(tableObj){
                                    var ret_phone = tableObj.get("phone");
                                      var ret_first = tableObj.get("firstName");
                                      var ret_last = tableObj.get("lastName");
                                      var ret_status = tableObj.get("redemption_status");
                                      var ret_vipCode = tableObj.get("vipCode");

                                      loc_json.data.push([count,ret_first +" "+ret_last,ret_phone,tableObj.get("createdAt"),ret_vipCode]); //construction of local json
                                      count++;
                                      console.log("finished fetching data for "+ret_first+" "+ret_last);
                                  },
                                  error: function(object, error) {
                                        console.log("could not do something "+error.message);
                                  }
                                });
                        }
                      console.log("success function end");
                  },
                  error: function(error){
                      console.log(error.message);
                  }
              });
    console.log("trying to return json");
    return loc_json;
}  



    var rows_selected = [];
    console.log("table creation");
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      ajax: getDataFromParse(),       // ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/4qr1g', THIS WORKS!!
      columns: [
        {},
        { data: 1},
        { data: 2 },
        { data: 3 }
      ],
      'columnDefs': [{
        'targets': 0,
        'searchable':false,
        'orderable':false,
        'className': 'dt-body-center',
        'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
          return '<input type="checkbox">';
        }
      }],
      'order': [1, 'asc'],
      'rowCallback': function(row, data, dataIndex){
        // Get row ID
        $('input.editor-active', row).prop( 'checked', data[3] == 1 )
        var rowId = data[0];

        // If row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
        if($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1){
          $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
          $(row).addClass('selected');
             console.log("table trying to create itself");
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Added jQuery and Parse.com CDN but getting "Uncaught Error: You need to call Parse.initialize before using Parse." I'm guessing because there are no "APPLICATION ID" or "JAVASCRIPT KEY". Perhaps set up a dummy project and add an ID and Key? There also needed to be a table with the id of example... (http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/t6xj4wks/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I've created a new app with some sample data in it, and updated your fiddle. it can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/t6xj4wks/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

1. Remove `ajax` option from DataTables initialization options.
2. Call `getDataFromParse()` after initializing the DataTable
3. In the `success` handler for each query, replace this line:

   ```
   loc_json.data.push([count, ret_first + " " + ret_last, ret_phone, tableObj.get("createdAt"), ret_vipCode]);
   ```

   with the line below to add a new row to the table.

   ```
   $('#example').DataTable()
      .row.add([
         count, 
         ret_first + " " + ret_last, 
         ret_phone, 
         tableObj.get("createdAt"), 
         ret_vipCode
      ])
      .draw(false);
   ```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qLccwq0/3/) for code and demonstration.

> **NOTES**

- The drawback of this solution is that a new row would be added once each query finishes successfully. Not sure if it is possible with Parse.com to handle event when all queries are completed.
- Your example uses jQuery DataTables 1.9 but you're using option names and API from 1.10. You need to upgrade your jQuery DataTables library.
- You're supplying data to jQuery DataTables using `ajax` option were in fact you should be using [`data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option instead.
- Remove code after `// FOR TESTING ONLY` as it was needed for demonstration only in [jQuery DataTables - Row selection using checkboxes](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) article and is not needed for production.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. It seems that the table creation function is still executed first, and only afterwards the `loc_json` is being populated. The console first shows "table creation" message and only then this line is executed `console.log("finished fetching data for "+ret_first+" "+ret_last);`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @undroid, you're right. I missed the code that there are additional asynchronous `query.get()`, I have updated my solution.

Comment: Thanks! It works quite well, now I'm able to receive the data, but the odd thing is that the table is actually shows data only if I click on one of the headers of the table. Seems like it refreshes the table to show the data.

Comment: @undroid, I have corrected the code, you need to add [`draw(false)`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) to update the table after adding each row, see my answer for code.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!